# JSON Response not holding field names of java object

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am parsing a 3rd party API Response into a custom class I made which seems to work fine. However, the JSON response from my own controller does not contain any field names of these objects. In code, the getters and setters work, but the JSON response is just an array of arrays like the original 3rd party API response I was trying to map.

Here is the service method where I parse to my custom java object class

```
    public List<Kline>klines(String symbol, String interval) {
    try {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        parameters.put("symbol", symbol);
        parameters.put("interval", interval);
        String result = client.createMarket().klines(parameters);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(result, new TypeReference<List<Kline>>() { });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the custom class I am trying to map the original 3rd party API response to

```
@GetMapping("/klines")
public List<Kline> klines() {
    return service.klines("BTCUSDT", "1h");
}
```

[image: My Controllers JSON Response - no field names]

My Pojo Class

```
@Data
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "openTime", "open", "high", "low", "close", 
"volume", "closeTime", "quoteAssetVolume",
    "numberOfTrades", "takerBuyBaseAssetVolume", 
"takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume" })
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Kline {

private Long openTime;

private double open;

private double high;

private double low;

private double close;

private double volume;

private Long closeTime;

private double quoteAssetVolume;

private int numberOfTrades;

private double takerBuyBaseAssetVolume;

private double takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume;

}
```

Comment: Well you've explicitly annotated the class with `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)`. How would you expect the field names to be expressed in an array?

Comment: the original 3rd party API response I was tryxing to map to java objects looks exactly like my controllers response. The original 3rd party api response has no field names, but I need field names thats why I am trying to map in the first place.

Comment: Okay, it's really not clear from the question that you're trying to change the shape of the JSON. it would help if you'd provide a *minimal* example, with the incoming JSON and the expected resulting JSON *in text* rather than as an image. I suspect you may need to have two different classes: one with an array shape and one with an object shape.

Comment: what is weird for me is that basically after mapping to my pojo, logging the pojo.toString() everything looks correct. Only my RestControllers response List<myPojo> returns an array containing multiple arrays without field names still instead of the pojo structure.

Comment: Well yes, because presumably `pojo.toString()` isn't taking account of the `@JsonFormat` you've got declared, but your controller is. That doesn't surprise me at all.

Comment: I dont understand unfortunatly

Comment: Your `Kline` class *specifically* is annotated with `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)`. I believe that means "Hey, JSON formatter - please serialize instances of this type as arrays rather than objects." Do you understand that much? (It's likely you need that in order to parse the incoming JSON - but if you want to format outgoing JSON in a different way, my guess is you'll need a different class that doesn't have that annotation...)

Comment: Ah yes I was not too sure about that. In fact, whenever I left out that annotation I got an error trying to map the incoming JSON thats why I thought it is  correct to leave that on.  So basically I need a class like PojoResponse and map that to Pojo without array annotation?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by PojoResponse here, but as I said 6 hours ago: "I suspect you may need to have two different classes: one with an array shape and one with an object shape." Either that, or you'll need a different way of influencing the parser/formatter. I don't know the details of JSON in Java, but at least hopefully you now understand what's going on.

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean, will try to come up with a way and try out